# How to bypass the Error 403 with scrapy and selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I have the example code write in scrapy with selenium.
Do you know how to bypass the 403 error?
I changed the setting

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3 # change delay time
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   "testfx.middlewares.TestfxDownloaderMiddleware": 543,
   'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800,
   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
   'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
   'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RetryUserAgentMiddleware': 401,
} # change the proxy
But it still have not worked.
```

I also add the HEADER with User-Agent.

```
import scrapy
import time

from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class BarchartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    START_URL = "https://www.barchart.com/forex/us-dollar"
    name = "barchart"
    allowed_domains = ["www.barchart.com"]
    start_urls = [START_URL]
    
    HEADERS = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    }
        
    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url=self.START_URL,
            wait_time=3,
            screenshot=True,
            callback=self.parse
        )
        
    def parse(self, response):   
        driver = response.meta['driver']
        currencies = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".row._grid_columns.selected")
        driver.save_screenshot('driver_screenshot.png')

        for currency in currencies:
            yield {
                "name": currency.css("._cell.symbolName::text").get()
            }
        pass
```

And the result is blocked by something:
[image]

Could you provide me some solution for this problem?